# Having issues requesting videos for a channel when the channel ID comes from a text file (PHP)

Tags: php, youtube

I have an issue getting the youtube api to work when I set some of the parameters to variables that are extracted from a text file. 
I have a list of channelids that grows that I need to use to know which channels I need videos from. 
When I assign the variable directly in the code it works fine. 
When i cycle through the text file and insert each channel id into the url one by one my file_get_contents returns nothing.

When I do a print_r to see if the request url is correct when pulling channelId from file the url is actually correct. If i copy that to the browser or even do a curl request from the command line it actually works.

For some reason, however, the file_get_contents seems to return nothing for the same url.

I thought originally that the issue was that I needed to set allow_url_fopen to On so that I could use something from a file in the url in php. 
This unfortunately didn't fix the issue.

function that I want to pass variable into

```
function createList($API_key,$channelID,$maxResults)   {


 $request = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=".$channelID."&key=".$API_key."&maxResults=".$maxResults;
 $videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents($request));
//processes list
}
```

working:

```
createList ($API_key, 'UC1sELGmy5jp5fQUugmuYlXQ', $maxResults, $request);
```

not working:

```
function whitelist($API_key, $maxResults)  {

    $handle = fopen("channels.txt", "r");

    if ($handle) {

        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

            $channel = $line;
            createList($API_key, $channel, $maxResults);        
        }

        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    }
}

whitelist($API_key, $maxResults, $request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are some "hidden characters" like a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) or [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) at the beginning or end of the lines you get from your textfile.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply and save me hours! I did a string replace of \n and \r to '' and that solved the problem!